Google Chrome ERR SSL KEY USAGE INCOMPATIBLE Chrome 124+
Started seeing the following error message after Chrome updated to v124 and above:
This site can't be reached
The webpage at XXXX.com might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE
Previously, we had a RegEdit in place https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled
RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled DWORD 0 that disabled a security check:
"The X.509 key usage extension declares how the key in a certificate may be used. Such instructions ensure certificates are not used in an unintended context, which protects against a class of cross-protocol attacks on HTTPS and other protocols. For this to work, HTTPS clients must check that server certificates match the connection's TLS parameters.
Starting in Google Chrome 124, this check is always enabled."
In 124 and above it says this check is ALWAYS enabled. We don't have the option at the moment of changing our internal SSL cert to meet requirements.. is there a way to disable this check in v124 and above somehow??
Tried removing the RegEdit than adding it back.. clearing cache / cookies etc etc. Basic troubleshooting steps

It's clearly not configurable. Might be simpler to rollback to 123 until you update the cert.

Is there a simple clean way to rollback? I've been searching online and can't really find anything.

Related:https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/269732161
